# How to embed a form view into Django's function-based detail view

Tags: django, forms

It should be a common situation, but I cannot find the right approach in the Django documentation or in numerous Django-related tutorials on the internet. So probably I just don't know what to look for, or there is no special approach. I am a hobby programmer and have just started with Django, so definitely lack a lot of knowledge but I am also looking for the best practices, not just workarounds.

I have a function-based detail view which displays a photo and comments. So urls.py contains:

```
app_name = 'photos'
urlpatterns = [url(r'^(?P<photo_id>\d+?)', views.single_photo_page, name="single-photo"),]
```

In views.py:

```
@login_required
def single_photo_page(request, photo_id: str):
    photo = get_photo_by_id(photo_id)
    if photo:
        return render(request, 'photos/single_photo.html', {'photo': photo})
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Photo %d not found' % photo_id)
```

single_photo.html:

```
<h1>{{ photo.id }}</h2>
<img src="{{ photo.image.url }}"/>
{% for comment in photo.comment_set.all|dictsort:"creation_timestamp" %}
  <div>
    <p>{{ comment.signature }}</p>
    <div>{{ comment.body|linebreaksbr|urlize }}</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

To accept user comments, I wanted to use Django's form functionality, but couldn't find how to embed a form into an existing view. So I've done it by hand:

view.py:

```
@login_required
def single_photo_page(request, photo_id: str):
    photo = get_photo_by_id(photo_id)
    try:
        new_comment_body = request.POST['comment-body']
        if new_comment_body:
            comment = Comment.objects.create(
                author=request.user,
                body=new_comment_body,
                photo=photo
            )
            comment.save()
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Empty comment')
    except KeyError:
        # no comment body in the request, so it's not a request from the form
        pass
    if photo:
        return render(request, 'photos/single_photo.html', {'photo': photo})
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Photo %d not found' % photo_id)
```

single_photo.html, after comment rendering:

```
<form action="{% url 'photos:single-photo' photo.id %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="comment-body">Add comment</label><br />
  <textarea id="comment-body"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

This approach works fine, but means that I do manually the stuff for which Django form functionality is designed. Am I missing something, or is the right way to do it?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: Have you seen class-based views? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: @DanielRoseman, not sure what you want to say. I know that page of course, it describes how to create a form view. I want to embed a form into a detail view. Maybe I misunderstand something, an answer with an example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Wtower, yes, but haven't tried them, as I understood it was just another way to create more advanced views in comparison to function-based views. Have I missed something?

Comment: @texnic I think your question is not very clear then. What exactly do you mean "I couldn't find a way to embed a form into a view."? You are using func-based views with form handling (presumambly, no relevant code posted), and you say it doesn't feel right. The class-based (cbv) approach tides things up a bit. Under that section, there is a chapter on forms and later on mixins, all of them should cover your case really.

Comment: @Wtower, sorry, I tried to make it clear. The view is func-based; as I mentioned, my view.py contains `def single_photo_page(request, photo_id: str)`, which renders a page. My problem: all handling is done manually, i.e. I parse request.POST by hand (ok, with Python), not Django. The template refers to the detail view URL, not form URL, as in documentation. The form rendering is also done by pure HTML. The "thank you" page is the same detail view. So I don't use any Django form functionality, e.g. no chance of using `{{ form.as_table }}` in the template. That's what I am missing.

Comment: @Wtower, perhaps mixins (an advanced topic for me so far) is the answer to my question, but I haven't got it from your comment. If that's what you mean, I appreciate the input. It would be awesome if you could post an example as an answer.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're making between a "form view" and a "detail view'. Views are just views: they accept requests and return responses.

Comment: @texnic I would be happy to post an example, but I too do not understand very well your problem. What does using `{{ form.as_table }}` has got anything to do with the view? If I start understanding better, you have an overall concern about django forms, but I would recommend you to break your problem into smaller pieces that will be easier to communicate.

Comment: @Wtower, Daniel, I start suspecting that I don't understand what a view is. I thought view was a way to generate an HTML page. In that sense, it can either generate an "active" form page, that can take input, pass it back to the view, that view validates it, returns errors etc. or a "passive" detail page containing no forms. Is that a wrong understanding? I can try to reformulate the question to: Could you please post a minimal example on how to put, in one page, some model-based data, e.g. a simple "article" with just `body = models.TextField` and a form to comment on that article?

Comment: @texnic well the django term for view is an often misconception: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names . I would also really urge you to take a look at the django tutorial on forms, it is not too difficult but a broad area for a SO answer. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: @Wtower,  I've not taken that tutorial but instead used it to build my custom solution. That's exactly where my misunderstanding is coming from: I can make things work, I just don't create or use any Django's form views. I will make sure to take it, maybe I missed something when reading. Thanks. In the meantime I've updated the view code in the question to hopefully  make the question more clear.